# OpenGL update parts of VBO (point cloud)

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

I have a udp client for reading points from a server that generates points in 4 msec and each packet have near 3000 points. i read this points and map them to a matrix with 1 million elements of coordinates. (i create a hash table from streamed points with fixed keys. i mean you can think of a 1000 keys and each key has maximum 1000 points but its varying. after completing this table any new value i get from server, map to my keys in a sorted manner, i mean, i updated points in smaller keys first and ... :D

i really shamed i cant do this, my LCD with 1990x1080 pixels do this so faster than me!! :-((

i want to insert this to a VBO and then upgrading each key parts in 30 ms.

so i want to create 1000 vbos for drawing and 1000 vbos for buffering and after each 33 ms iteration i change 50 vbos of drawing ones with buffering ones. each vbo has maximum 0f 1000 points and colors, and number of points in one VBO change from 10 to 1000;

my problem start here i don't understand how VBO's work and best solution for implementation of this problem? :D

1- my first question: why i create a VAO and how its associated to new gen buffers?
its look like its associated to exactly next glGenBuffer() right? but in any sample i read i don't see any using of this pointer (just use for draw)? this is my code for creating a vbo i downloaded from somewhere

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayObject);
glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);

// First see if the vertex array buffer has been created...
if(uiVertexArray == 0) {    // Nope, we need to create it
    glGenBuffers(1, &uiVertexArray);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiVertexArray);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3 * nNumVerts, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
}

// Now see if it's already mapped, if not, map it
if(pVerts == NULL) {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiVertexArray);
    pVerts = (M3DVector3f *)glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
}

// Ignore if we go past the end, keeps things from blowing up
if(nVertsBuilding >= nNumVerts)
    return;

// Copy it in...
pVerts[nVertsBuilding][0] = x;
pVerts[nVertsBuilding][1] = y;
pVerts[nVertsBuilding][2] = z;
nVertsBuilding++;
```

for color and texture mapping its look like. which has better performance (GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW, GL_STREAM_DRAW)

2- this is a draw function? why use last line? for creating the next VBO and VAO?

```
// Set up the vertex array object
glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);
glDrawArrays(primitiveType, 0, nNumVerts);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

3- in the next time i want change a buffered VBO contents with new points i must do this all again for different number of points and if i do this i must delete last buffer of VBO or not?

```
// Vertex buffer objects
if(uiVertexArray != 0)
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &uiVertexArray);
```

4- can i resize my VBOs and don't use recreate buffer VBO's?

5- How to copy data from buffer VBO's to draw VBO's?

this is my swap buffers with draw VBO's in main draw function, i recreate VBO data from first in swap function

```
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    if(must_show_buffer(i))
    {
          bufferVBO[i].draw();
          drawedVBO[i].swap(bufferVBO[i]);
    } 
    else drawedVBO[i].draw();
```

UPDATE:

i use this functions for swap data:
    if(batch->cVerts != NULL)
    {
        CopyVertexData3f(batch->cVerts);
        CopyColorData4f(batch->cColors);
    }
    End();

```
void GLBatch::CopyColorData4f(M3DVector4f *vColors)
{
// First time, create the buffer object, allocate the space
if(uiColorArray == 0) {
    glGenBuffers(1, &uiColorArray);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiColorArray);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 4 * nNumVerts, vColors, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
}
else {  // Just bind to existing object
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiColorArray);

    // Copy the data in
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLfloat) * 4 * nNumVerts, vColors);
    pColors = NULL;
    }
 }
```

this approach is work correct but glBufferSubData increase memory usage so fast and i get a memory out exception

and this approach

```
    if(batch->uiVertexArray != NULL)
    {
    // First time, create the buffer object, allocate the space
    if(uiVertexArray == 0) {
        glGenBuffers(1, &uiVertexArray);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiVertexArray);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3 * nNumVerts, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    }

    // Fast copy data
    glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, batch->uiVertexArray);
    glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, uiVertexArray);
    glCopyBufferSubData(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, 0, 0, nNumVerts);
    glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, 0);

    //copy color data
    if(uiColorArray == 0) {
        glGenBuffers(1, &uiColorArray);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiColorArray);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 4 * nNumVerts, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    }

    glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, batch->uiColorArray);
    glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, uiColorArray);
    glCopyBufferSubData(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, 0, 0, nNumVerts);
    glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

without memory allocation problem but doesn't clear before points

what i miss in each implementation?

Comment: To many questions in one post IMHO.

Comment: Why you don't use the wiki and man pages? (http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/ http://www.opengl.org/wiki/) Your questions are basic, it's easy to find answers on these sites.

Comment: may be for you but i dont understand copy and resizing section? and i want to know its the good implementation or worst

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. VBOs are associated to the currently bound VAO during glVertexAttribPointer
2. unbinding buffers is a good practice, remember that bind state is global and the less global state you rely on the better
3. no need to delete the VBO you can just skip the `glGenBuffers(1, &uiVertexArray);` call
4. yes a new call to `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3 * nNumVerts, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);` with the new nNumVerts will resize the buffer (and thrash any existing data)
5. you can do the following:

   ```
   glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, bufferVBO);
   glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, drawVBO);
   glCopyBufferSubData(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER​, GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER​, 0​, 0, size​);
   glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, 0);
   glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, 0);
   ```

I have written out 700k points/s to the screen no problem simply by uploading them all into a single VBO and drawing that.

Comment: thanks for your answers in 2 you mean for resizing of a VBO i must just call this two commands and dont delete main buffer: glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiVertexArray);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3 * nNumVerts, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

Comment: and when i must use GL_STREAM_DRAW?

Comment: this answer help me alot but i cant solve my problem with vbos so i use array vectors :D